# Wordpress: Get custom taxonomies and taxonomy terms

Tags: php, wordpress

This code is 95% working, but I need some help with the last part. I am trying to fetch all the custom taxonomies and taxonomy terms from Wordpress and display them in an unordered list. Here is my code:

```
$args=array('public'   => true, '_builtin' => false); 
        $output = 'names';
        $operator = 'and';
        $taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 
        if  ($taxonomies) {
          foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
            echo '<a>'. $taxonomy. '</a>';
            $terms = get_terms("color");
            $count = count($terms);
            if ( $count > 0 ){
                echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";
                    }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
          }
        }
```

The problem is on line 8 where it reads `$terms = get_terms("color");`. I wrote this as a means to test the code but the problem is that Wordpress now displays the terms from the taxonomy 'color' for every taxonomy.

How would I modify this code so that for each taxonomy Wordpress displays, it would also display the corresponding list of terms for that taxonomy?

Comment: Being a PHP novice, I thought this would work `$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
```

In this case, `$taxonomy` is not an object but an array of the taxonomy names (`$output = 'names'`). Therefore. `$taxonomy->name` does not work.

See:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Comment: Thank you Danilo! I swear I tried that. I even wrote it in the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to display all taxonomies:

```
Taxonomy1
-Terms1a
-Terms1b
-etc

Taxonomy2
-Terms2a
-Terms2b
-etc
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php  
$args=array('public'   => true, '_builtin' => false); 
$output = 'names';
$operator = 'and';
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
    foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
        echo '<a>'. $taxonomy. '</a>';
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
        $count = count($terms);
        if ( $count > 0 ){
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $termlinks= get_term_link($term,$taxonomy);
                ?> <a href="<?php echo $termlinks; ?>">
                <?php echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>"; ?></a><?php
            }
        echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$terms = get_terms($taxonomy->name);` ?

Comment: I tried that, as well as `$terms = get_terms(get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ));`. No dice :(

Comment: oo didn't see that the output is names try `$terms = get_terms($taxonomy['name'])`